# Lie groups and NSS+LC group

Tags: lie-groups, reference-request

1. Let $G$ be a locally compact group without small subgroups. Is $G$  a "finite" dimensional  Lie group? (i.e, $G$ is not infinite dimensional Lie group.)
2. Are Lie groups precisely the locally Euclidean topological groups?

I need exact answer and exact references for the above questions.
Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: What do you mean by small subgroups?
For question 2, you also need the topology to be countably generated.

Comment: A topological group $G$ *has no small subgroups* if there is a neighborhood $U$ of the identity such that no nontrivial subgroup of $G$ is contained in $U$. By Gleason-Yamabe-Montgomery-Zippin, a locally compact group with no small subgroups is isomorphic to a real analytic Lie group (of finite dimension, with an arbitrary number of components).

Answer (score 4):

Yes to both question (at least for separable groups):

MR0379739  Reviewed Montgomery, Deane; Zippin, Leo Topological transformation groups. Reprint of the 1955 original. Robert E. Krieger Publishing Co., Huntington, N.Y., 1974. xi+289 pp.

MR0049204  Reviewed Montgomery, Deane; Zippin, Leo Small subgroups of finite-dimensional groups. Ann. of Math. (2) 56, (1952). 213–241.

Comment: Separability is, of course, needed, otherwise you can take an uncountable group with discrete topology. 

Comment: Depending on courage, taste, and (bad?) judgement one could allow Lie groups with uncountably many connected components.

Comment: to sustain Peter's comment: an uncountable discrete group is certainly  a Lie group, is finite-dimensional (indeed 0-dimensional), and has no small subgroups. If there is a separability issue, it might only incurs at a local level, but actually I don't think it's relevant, i.e. I think Peter's answer is correct without separability assumption.

Comment: Peter: A Lie group is supposed to be a manifold; the latter is always (to the best of my knowledge) assumed to be 2nd countable. Incidentally, I thought that you also need to assume that the group  is Hausdorff, but maybe this could be derived from "no small subgroups" assumption...

Comment: @Misha: a manifold is not assumed to be second countable, as far as I know, except for expository issues.

Comment: @Yves: I never heard or read of this. I guess, we are just reading different books and papers. With this definition, many things become very problematic, like topological classification of acyclic surfaces (or maybe even curves) becomes an open problem. 

Comment: @Misha: I think the most usual convention is to assume that connected components are second countable, or equivalently that manifolds are paracompact.

Comment: For a connected Lie group (or locally Euclidean topological group) $G$, 2nd countability is a consequence of being locally Euclidean, since $G$ is generated by any neighborhood of the identity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to both questions, assuming that the group $G$ is locally compact and
Hausdorff. In such a group one can always find an open subgroup $H$ which
is isomorphic to $(K\times L)/\Gamma$, where $K$ is compact, $L$ is a
$1$-connected Lie group and $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of $K\times L$. 
This reduces
both questions (or assumptions) to the compact group $K$. No topological countability assumptions are needed.